# Jssor Slider replace navigator number to bullets

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using a Jssor slider with navigator and I want to replace the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 by bullets we usually use in HTML or image bullets.
What is the option managing that ?
I have searched and I did not find anything about it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please just remove (delete) following code,

```
<NumberTemplate></NumberTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just replaced it with one bullet and it solved my problem. Thanks ;)